# Why is my datapack so laggy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

https://www.planetminecraft.com/data-pack/aceplante-s-rl-megapack-for-1-17/

For every single function I have added so far, I have been careful to add tag checks. For example, if I want to replace the held item of skeletons, I will only run that command at skeletons without the tag, then add it after so it doesn't run again.

So I am not sure why I am experiencing lag since as far as I can tell, everything is written as efficiently as possible. I tried debug but I do not seem to be getting a file as google claims I should.

[image]

I guess my question is what are some of the reasons it might be laggy? Is there a way I can find out what part of it specifically is causing the lag?

Answer (score 2):

There are many many reasons why a datapack may be laggy, and it is hard to diagnose the issue(s) without knowing what it does. But, here are some common reasons that I can list off the top of my head:

- Too many entities (e.g. using too many armorstands)
- High usage of heavy entity selectors (e.g. using `@e` a high amount of times)
- NBT (reading, writing, or accessing entity NBT data is extremely laggy. Like `execute if entity @e[nbt=...]`)
- Large clone/fill commands
- Recursive functions, or in general, too many commands per tick (we're talking hundreds of thousands)

Comment: So im not using armor stands or clone/fill at all, but I am checking @e[type=somemob] a lot, but doesnt that only target a single type of entity? And like I said I am using tags to make sure it only runs once. Would it help to attach it?

Comment: Attaching your datapack would be very helpful, as the information you gave us in your question is not enough to determine the exact cause

Comment: `@e[tag=...]` still needs to find all entities and then filter them. Use subfunctions to prevent duplicate checks and use `@s` inside them instead. Also using `@e[type=...,tag=...]` can be more efficient even if it is in theory redundant, if only one type is possible, because type checks are really fast.